# Hide comments in R markdown

Tags: r, latex, markdown, knitr

Is is possible to hide some comments in code when kniting using knitr / R markdown? Example:

````
---
title: "SOSO"
author: "SO"
date: '2017-06-06'
output: pdf_document


---

```{r}

# Generate some data

rnorm(2)

## But keep this comment

```
````

When kniting I would like the first comment to disapear, but keep the second one somehow.

Comment: You could write a custom [output hook](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/) that removes lines based on whatever criteria you would like.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a quick example of modifying the hook to change knitr behavior.

````
---
title: "SOSO"
author: "SO"
date: 2017-06-06
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup-hook, echo=FALSE}
hook_in <- function(x, options) {
    x <- x[!grepl("^#\\s+", x)]
    paste0("```r\n",
          paste0(x, collapse="\n"),
          "\n```")
}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(source = hook_in)
```

```{r}

# Generate some data
# Lines that starts with `# ` will be removed from the rendered documents

rnorm(2)

## But keep this comment
## But lines that starts with `## ` will be kept

```
````

produces this[image]

Comment: This strategy does not seem to work if sourcing from a separate R script using `knitr::read_chunk`

Answer (score 6):

In fact, you can choose to show any lines of R code by passing numeric indices to the chunk option `echo`, e.g.

````
---
title: "SOSO"
author: "SO"
date: '2017-06-06'
output: pdf_document
---

```{r echo=4:7}

# Generate some data

rnorm(2)

## But keep this comment

```
````

See [**knitr** documentation](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) for more information.

Comment: This is a far more elegant solution than the accepted answer. Though the accepted answer is quite clever.